# Custom Picker Editor Control

Tags: 2007

I have lookup column, but the data in this column is very large.I want to create a custom picker control like (people editor control) in sharepoint.
Please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post: http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/index.php/2009/10/create-a-custom-picker-in-sharepoint-2010/